# Get URL of current module script

Tags: javascript, html, ecmascript-6

I haven't found any mentions in the [HTML spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/) nor anywhere on the web, that says this is possible, still I ask just in case.

Is it possible to get the URL of a module to for example fetch files relative to that URL?

Let's say my `index.html` has a:

```
<script type="module">import '/foo/foo.js'</script>
```

and `foo.js` wants to know what it's own url is to load dynamically some file e.g. `./file-inside-foo`.

As of the time of this writing `document.currentScript` returns `null` inside modules and is probably like that by design?

Comment: ok, I found this https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/1013 it seems it's still an open issue

Answer (score 10):

You can use `import.meta`. On the web this exposes a property named `url` that, when accessed from within a module, gives access to the full URL of that module.

```
// in /path/to/your/module.js

const { pathname } = new URL(import.meta.url);
console.log(pathname); // '/path/to/your/module.js'
```

You can also use the second parameter of the `URL` constructor to skip a step here:

```
const url = new URL('relative/file.js', import.meta.url);
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import.meta) which exposes a property named `url` providing the full path to the current module including the protocol and filename.

```
// import.meta.url == 'http://your.domain.name/path/to/your/module.js'
```

To get the path of the current module without the protocol + domain you can construct a [URL](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL) object from this value and access its `.pathname` property:

```
const modulePath = new URL(import.meta.url).pathname;
// modulePath = '/path/to/your/module.js'
```

To determine the directory where the current module is located you would construct a URL object for the relative path `./` using `import.meta.url` as the `base` parameter:

```
const moduleDir = new URL('./', import.meta.url).pathname;
// moduleDir == '/path/to/your/'
```

You can also get the path of any file relative to the current module in the same manner. For example:

```
let img = new Image();
image.src = new URL('../icons/glyph.png', import.meta.url).pathname;
// image.src == '/path/to/icons/glyph.png'
```

Comment: please use `new URL(import.meta.url)` to parse a URL, not manually splitting.

Comment: `const { modulePath } = new URL('./', import.meta.url).pathname;` should be `const modulePath = new URL('./', import.meta.url).pathname;` or `const { pathname: modulePath } = new URL('./', import.meta.url);`

Comment: I feel I should point out that @snek is a contributor to these proposed standards and part of the reason these great new features exist. His contributions to both the web and this answer should be noted.

Comment: thanks :) But I haven't put any work into the import.meta proposal or URL standard. There are other people who should get credit long before I do.