# How to get currentScript if it has type="module"

Tags: javascript

I enqueue JS file as a script with `type="module"` and need to get the `src` attribute of the script inside the script

But if I trying

```
document.currentScript
```

it returns `null`

Is there a similar way as `currentScript` for `type="module"` ?

---

Ok, I see there is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46691735/3208225) so I've closed my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### import.meta

You can use [`import.meta`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/import.meta).

#### For example:

In `page.html`:

```
<script src="module1.js" type="module"></script>
```

In `module1.js`:

```
import './module2.js';
console.log(import.meta);
```

In `module2.js`:

```
console.log(import.meta);
```