# TS read file from script path

Tags: javascript, typescript, file

I'm doing a library in Typescript on which I need to read some files.
I know that it's possible using `fetch(url)` where `url` corresponds to the relative path to the file from the html page.
The only problem is that I don't know where the html page will be located since that will be the job of the user.
So my question is, how do I get a file, from my project, using a relative path from the script I'm calling `fetch()` (or any other function).

[image: An image to help you understading my question]

For exemple, I want to read a file on the "Shader" dir, from "Material.ts".

The file I need to read is plain text, and my scripts are using import statments so they are already a module.

I've tried document.currentScript.src but I get an error.

Comment: use `import` instead, eg `import something from "../shader/somemodule"`

Comment: Does it works if it's plain text ?

Comment: You'd need some type of bundler that allows you to load those files. Like webpack or parcel or similar. Missed that they were plaintext files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `import.meta.url` returns the path of the current script of a module.

Using this command it's possible to get the path of something else related to this script.
The URL API is really usefull for that:

```js
new URL("../Shader/someShader.frag", import.meta.url).pathname;
```

this returns the path of the ressource I was looking for !

Sources :

1. [Get URL of current module script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46691735/get-url-of-current-module-script)
2. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL